# Plot variable 1 against variable 2 with curves grouped by variable 3 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have this very simple problem which I can't figure out in Python. I have three columns in a dataset. The  the first is made of integers (from 0 to 19), the second is made of dates in Y/M/D format, and the third is made of numbers ranging from negative to positive values (mostly 0s, but 200 negative and positive values in total overall).

My dataset looks like that:

```
Groups           date          values    
0                2020-02-22     0.0000
                 2020-02-23     0.0000
                 2020-02-26     0.0000
                 2020-03-28     0.0000
                 2020-04-13     1.3433
                 2020-04-14     0.0000
                 2020-04-15     0.0000
                 2020-04-16     0.0000
                 2020-04-17     -1.3933
                 2020-04-28     0.0000
                 2020-05-31     0.0000
                 2020-06-15     0.0000
                 2020-08-02     0.0000
1                2020-02-21     0.0000
                 2020-02-22     0.0000
                 2020-02-23     0.0000
                 2020-02-24     0.0000
                 2020-02-25     0.0000
                 2020-04-29     0.0000
                 2020-06-01     0.4404
                 2020-06-02     0.4404
                 2020-06-07     0.0000
2                2020-02-22     0.0000
                 2020-02-23     0.0000
                 2020-02-24     0.0000
                 2020-02-28     0.0000
                 2020-03-01     0.0000
                 2020-03-07     0.0000
                 2020-03-08     0.0000
                 2020-03-14     0.0000
```

I want to plot curves grouped by column Groups, with the dates on the x axis and the third column ("values") on the y axis. In other words, I want a curve for each of the 20 possible groups (0 to 19) which goes up/down depending on the values of the third column, "value" (the 0s, positive, and negative numbers), all the while keeping the dates on the x axis.

I know how to do this very easily with ggplot on R but this project is all Python based and for some reason I just can't find how to do this there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Groups` and `date` are the two levels of your dataframe's index. In which casem You can do:

```
df['values'].unstack('Groups').plot()
```